# why Vuetify does not work in my Nuxt app?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using **Vuetify** in my Nuxt app. I just started a new project with **create-nuxt-app** command in my windows and I selected the **Vuetify** as the **UI framework**. after the project files was built this is the section of my **nuxt.config.js** file that is related to **Vuetify**:

```js
// Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    buildModules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/vuetify
        '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    ],

    // Vuetify module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-vuetify
    vuetify: {
        customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
        theme: {
            dark: true,
            themes: {
                dark: {
                    primary: colors.blue.darken2,
                    accent: colors.grey.darken3,
                    secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
                    info: colors.teal.lighten1,
                    warning: colors.amber.base,
                    error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
                    success: colors.green.accent3
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

After that I copied a piece of code from "Vuetify" [official website](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#justify) in one of my pages:

```html
<template>
  <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
    <v-row
      v-for="j in justify"
      :key="j"
      :justify="j"
    >
      <v-col
        v-for="k in 2"
        :key="k"
        md="4"
      >
        <v-card
          class="pa-2"
          outlined
          tile
        >
          One of two columns
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      justify: [
        'start',
        'center',
        'end',
        'space-around',
        'space-between',
      ],
    }),
  }
</script>
```

I think that it must work for me now, but the result in my browser is like this:

[image]

As you can see there is no justifying in "v-row" element. There are some errors in my console but I think there are not related, because in my chrome browser the output is the same and there is no error in console. What is the problem? Do I need another step for configuring "Vuetify" in my Nuxt app?

Comment: The configuration of vuetify and also the example code look fine. Something important for vuetify to work is that you wrap everything inside the `<v-app>`.
See the vuetify docs about the `<v-app>` component: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#api
A good place to use the v-app component would be the `layouts/default.vue` file.

Comment: @Felix Graf, thanks I added it in my **default.vue** and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Following @felixgraf I did the following:
Added the layouts/default.vue component to my nuxt app following these instructions: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/layouts

In the template, I wrote the following:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Nuxt />
  </v-app>
</template>
```